# Rotate an image by 90 degrees

Tags: java, matrix, image

Looking for review, good practices, optimizations, clean code tips etc.

```
final class Pixel {

    private final int color;

    public Pixel(int color) {
        this.color = color;
    }

    public int getColor() {
        return color;
    }
}

/**
 * Rotates an image by ninety degrees.
 * 
 * Complexity:
 * O(row * col)
 */
public final class Rotate {

    private Rotate() { }

    /**
     * Rotes the image in anti clockwise direction.
     * 
     * @param   image the image to be rotated.
     * @return  the titled image.
     * @throws  NPE
     */
    public static Pixel[][] rotateAntiClockWise(Pixel[][] image) {
        int col = image.length;
        int row = image[0].length;

        final Pixel[][] rotatedPixel = new Pixel[row][col];

        for (int i = 0; i < image.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < image[0].length; j++) {
                rotatedPixel[image[0].length -1 -j][i] = image[i][j];
            }
        }
        return rotatedPixel;
    }


    /**
     * Rotates the image in clockwise direction.
     * 
     * @param   image the image to be rotated.
     * @returns the rotated image.
     * @throws  NPE
     */
   public static Pixel[][] rotateClockWise(Pixel[][] image) {
       int col = image.length;
       int row = image[0].length;

       final Pixel[][] rotatedPixel = new Pixel[row][col];

       for (int i = 0; i < image.length; i++) {
           for (int j = 0; j < image[0].length; j++) {
               rotatedPixel[j][image.length -1 - i] = image[i][j];
           }
       }
       return rotatedPixel;
   }


   public static void main(String[] args) {
       //   int[][] m = { {1, 2, 3, 4} ,
       //                {10, 20, 30, 40}};
       Pixel[][] image = new Pixel[2][4];
       image[0][0] = new Pixel(1);
       image[0][1] = new Pixel(2);
       image[0][2] = new Pixel(3);
       image[0][3] = new Pixel(4);

       image[1][0] = new Pixel(10);
       image[1][1] = new Pixel(20);
       image[1][2] = new Pixel(30);
       image[1][3] = new Pixel(40);

       Pixel[][] rotatedAntiClockNinetyDegreeImage = rotateAntiClockWise(image);

       /*
        * Expected: 
        * 
        * 4  40
        * 3  30
        * 2  20
        * 1  10
        * 
        */
       for (int i = 0; i < rotatedAntiClockNinetyDegreeImage.length; i++) {
           for (int j = 0; j < rotatedAntiClockNinetyDegreeImage[0].length; j++) {
               System.out.print(rotatedAntiClockNinetyDegreeImage[i][j].getColor() + " ");
           }
           System.out.println();
       }

       System.out.println("==========================================");


       Pixel[][] rotatedClockWiseNinetyDegreeImage = rotateClockWise(image);

       /*
        * Expected: 
        * 
        * 10  1 
        * 20  2
        * 30  3
        * 40  4  
        * 
        */
       for (int i = 0; i < rotatedClockWiseNinetyDegreeImage.length; i++) {
           for (int j = 0; j < rotatedClockWiseNinetyDegreeImage[0].length; j++) {
               System.out.print(rotatedClockWiseNinetyDegreeImage[i][j].getColor() + " ");
           }
           System.out.println();
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Assuming that you will want to do more interesting things with these images later, you should probably come up with a better OOP design.  I suggest:

```
public interface ImageTransformation {
    public Pixel[][] transform(Pixel[][] image);
}

public class Clockwise90Rotation implements ImageTransformation {
    ...
}

public class AntiClockwise90Rotation implements ImageTransformation {
    ...
}
```

It's practically no work to rearrange the code that way.  In return, you gain the flexibility to do things like:

```
ImageTransformation[] pipeline = new ImageTransformation[] {
    new Clockwise90Rotation(),
    new ContrastEnhancer(),
    new GaussianBlur(/* radius= */ 5)
};
for (ImageTransformation t : pipeline) {
    image = t.transform(image);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Overall, your code is really nice looking!  Below are just some basic suggestions.

```
final class Pixel {
```

In my opinion, you should always explicitly dictate whether classes are `public`, `private`, or `protected`.

```
public static Pixel[][] rotateAntiClockWise(Pixel[][] image) {
    int col = image.length;
    int row = image[0].length;
```

Here, your method assumes that every image is a rectangle of some kind.  If you had an image that was, say, a triangle, your code would fail with either a `NullPointerException` or an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` at some point (depending on which end of the triangle you started at).

```
final Pixel[][] rotatedPixel = new Pixel[row][col];
```

Out of curiosity, is there a reason you make this two-dimensional array `final`?  It doesn't affect the values stored in the arrays, and the `final` doesn't affect the reference when it's returned from the method, so there doesn't seem to be much value in having it here (unlike its use in your `Pixel` class, which makes perfect sense).

```
Pixel[][] rotatedAntiClockNinetyDegreeImage = rotateAntiClockWise(image);
```

This is of course pretty subjective, but this variable name is really, *really* verbose, even by Java standards.  `rotatedAntiClockwise` would be sufficient, or even just `rotated` for these purposes.  Just an opinion.

Comment: Is there any such thing as a triangle image? (A two-dimensional array of pixels that is not rectangular)

Comment: That seems trivial to prove, does it not?  Hard to type in comments without line breaks, but if the following statements are all true: `image[0].length = 1; image[1].length = 2; image[2].length = 3;` and so on.  If you're asking whether or not this exists in the wild, I assume so.  I suppose I could be wrong an all images are rectangular with, at best, transparent backgrounds, but such a categorical statement would seem odd to me.

Comment: Well I've always assumed that all images are rectangular in the computer world. They always have a width and a height. I think that introducing non-rectangular images would cause problems in a lot of areas. Of course it's possible to create a non-rectangular two-dimensional array of pixels with code, but does it **exist**? Is such an array ever serialized to a real image that is readable by standard image viewer applications?

Comment: Good point.  No idea, truthfully.